# How can I delete input in the terminal?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor

- Xubuntu 13.10

Say I paste a command, something like

```
sudo apt-get install abc yxz 123 DEF MMM KKK
```

into the terminal. Then I suddenly had a change in mind and thus I would like to delete the last 3 packages without using backspace. Is there a way to mark them, as in using something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using the "usual" bash with emacs bindings, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> should work.

To delete three words either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> three times or preceed it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>.

For more shortcuts have a look at [this list](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html).

Comment: Hm, in my terminal/bash conole, which is actually [`xfce4-terminal`](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start), the Alt+N trick changes to the tab N (I often have more than one tab open, the first one usually running `htop`).

Comment: That's why you usually can use ESC instead of Alt.

Comment: I see. Is there a shortcut (combination) to delete the whole input at once?

Comment: Ctrl-c or Ctrl-u will do that. For more like that have a look at [this](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html).

Comment: Lol, when you google your own questions... so I wanted to add: but if there's only one tab open, the `Alt+N` bit works pretty great! Neat. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Most shells have a facility called keybindings. It's of course configurable, and the designers of Bash opted to use keybindings that are similar to the text editor Emacs. Here's a cheatsheet that shows all the various keyboard shortcuts one can use from within a Bash shell to move the cursor within a given prompt, as well as delete whole words etc.

- [Mastering The Linux Shell – Bash Shortcuts Explained (Now With Cheat Sheets)](http://beerpla.net/2008/12/22/mastering-the-linux-shell-bash-shortcuts-explained/)
- [Cheatsheet as a PDF](http://beerpla.net/downloads/Bash.Shortcuts.pdf)
- [Bash Cheat Sheet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88404386/Bash-Cheat-Sheet)

This is of course my favorite because it's a picture so it's easier to associate which bindings go with which keys.

[image: ss of cheatsheet]

**Source:** *[Bash Cheat Sheet - SCRIBD](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88404386/Bash-Cheat-Sheet)*

Comment: Correction to the did-you-know box: control-c sends `SIGINT`, not `SIGTERM`. control-z actually suspends the job (sending `SIGSTOP` to the process group); you have to issue `bg` afterwards to make it continue in the background.

Comment: Also: control-pageup and control-pagedown don't do anything in `bash` on my Ubuntu box.

Comment: @BlacklightShining you're quite right about `SIGINT` of course but `Ctrl+Z` _does_ send a job to the background, whether it continues running is another issue. What is Ctrl+PgUp supposed to do? I don't see it in the image above.

Comment: @terdon Fair enough. I just found it misleading; I would interpret _send a process to the background_ as _make a process continue running in the background_. According to the image, control-pageup and control-pagedown are supposed to “scroll the terminal, even remote or graphical ones.”

Answer (score 2):

If you ran the command itself by mistake, in emacs editing mode you can use up-arrow to move to the last command, and edit it to a new command undoing the mistake. But note that not all commands can be cleanly undone, perhaps installing those packages installed others as dependencies or made other changes.

Depending on the exact commands (here package installation), there might be logs of what was done somewhere; using the logs you shold be able to figre out what was done (and thus how to undo it).

Get confortable editing the command line and rummaging in the history bash keeps. It is a work (and ocassionally life-) saver. And go into the habit of reading commands twice (thinking carefully what you want to do in between) before pressing ENTER if there is the slightest possibility of something destructive.

Comment: I am aware of some of the things you said, I usually don't have such "problems" which could have, as you said, some bad consequences. Thanks for reminding me though, I have yet to work through some guides for beginners. :) ([#1](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), [#2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-basics/))

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash` then you can do following

Alt-3 followed by Ctrl+w assuming you're at the end of command.

Explanation:

Alt+N is used to pass universal argument to the following command to be executed N number of times.

Ctrl+w deletes a word backward.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Unfortunately in my terminal/bash conole, which is actually [`xfce4-terminal`](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start), the Alt+N trick changes to the tab N (I often have more than one tab open, the first one usually running `htop`).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using bash. Bash default editing mode is emacs.
Bash supports both emacs mode and vi mode.

In Bash-Emacs and Bash-vi mode:

```
C-w (Control-w) will clear last word
```

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/